# Image floating right to div

Tags: html, css, image, css-float

I have a text block (a div) that needs to wrap around a image floating to the right. It doesn't work however.

This is what I have now:

```
<img style="float: right;" src="images/IMG_20130906_155859.jpg" alt="IMG 20130906 155859" width="200" height="267" />
<div class="customintro">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, quodsi pertinax ex mei, admodum corpora percipit ad cum. Recteque dignissim eu est. Ad vocent veritus has, quas movet complectitur no eos. Verear feugait ex mea, vix dicat congue eu, ne mel oratio appetere democritum. Qualisque sententiae est ei.Ei usu nostrum accusamus. Feugait temporibus ne sed, at clita eleifend nam, et dolor utinam equidem his. Vis sumo verterem ex, ut esse dolor appellantur his. Consul mentitum mnesarchum ne cum, saepe scaevola reformidans an mea, eu pri postea docendi invenire. Cum te soleat scaevola accusamus, ut sea euismod inimicus aliquando.Id noster incorrupte qui, quidam equidem vituperata ne sea. Odio probo persequeris ei sed, ea laudem electram per. Pro ea illum verear laoreet. Inani legimus contentiones eu per, id diceret consulatu pri, vitae cetero ad ius. In audiam necessitatibus nec, consequat appellantur mel te. Omnes cotidieque vix ea, quo iudico theophrastus et, in dolor option facilisi nam.</p></div>
```

CSS:

```
div.customintro {
padding: 10px;
background-color: #AAAAAA;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
}
```

This is the result:
[image]

As you can see, the text wraps around the image (that's great) but the div still is behind the image. How can I make the div stay left from the image? I fiddled around with different display styles but I can't make it work.

Of course it works when I set a width to the div, but I don't want that because the size of the image varies.

Comment: Can you share the fiddel demo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where the magic of `display: table-cell` comes to the rescue. Add on your `div.customintro` this display property. ([Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qUN6K/))

```
div.customintro {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #AAAAAA;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Notice that this doesn't work for Internet Explorer 7 (and lower) but you can add `display: inline-block` which provides the fallback.

Comment: display: table-cell? Well, it works perfectly! Thanks for you answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to `.customintro` div.

```
float:left;
width:calc(100% - 220px); //200px of image, 20px of padding
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/gsLja/)

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but the point is that I will use different images of different sizes. So the 200px of this example image will vary.

Comment: Use percentage in that case or go with Mike's solution.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler answer than the two already posted is to put your `<div>` and `<img>` as `display: inline-block` so they are treated as inline elements. Your `float` property should work as expected now.